# Tortoise SVN - Error:Delta Source Ended Unexpectedly

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When trying to perform an SVN update on a directory I get the above error, and as a result the changes to the files within this directory don't get pulled down to my working copy.  If I go to the repo-browser it can see the changes that have been made, but this error just seems to kill the update pull all together.

I've tried deleting the files in question and performed an SVN update, deleting the directory and even deleting the top-level directory and re-checking out the entire repository, but still get the same error.  After extensive googling this was the only approach I could find that had had some success.

I am running TortoiseSVN: 1.7.9 and Subversion 1.7.7

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted, had to do a top level delete of my local copy as well as delete the hidden .svn folder being the key part.  Then just do a fresh checkout of the repository.  Hope this is of some use to anybody who runs into this in the future at least.

Answer (score 5):

None of the other answers worked for me. Even completely deleting the local copy and checking it out again did not work.

Instead I followed the advice offered by http://www.tomaz.me/2014/01/01/resolving-delta-source-ended-unexpectedly-svn-issue.html:

- delete the file from the repository
- commit the deletion
- add the file again
- commit the addition

**EDIT**

As it turns out the fix above often helped to take care of the error for one commit only. Later on it reoccured. However, all affected files had spaces in their names. Renaming these files (e.g. eliminating the spaces) took care of the error more permanently.

Answer (score 1):

For added information (and the reason committing the deletion then re-adding the offensive file works) I found that this error cropped up when trying to commit the following:

> filename.JPG (original versioned file)
>
> filename.jpg   (the modified file I'm trying to commit)

It identifies as the same file, however the capitalisation difference causes the delta source error.

Answer (score 1):

Updating TortoiseSVN from 1.6 to 1.9 and then applying the "SVN Upgrade working copy" operation (through contextual menu in Windows Explorer) worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The file that caused the error was linked with svn:external.
I first tried to delete / recommit the real file, which didn't help.
Then i removed the link and added it again, which solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had to go back to an svn client < 1.7 that uses the old svn client file format. So I installed the latest 1.6 version of TortoiseSVN (1.6.17), which up to now works fine.

To give a bit of background: As of SVN version 1.7 a new client file format based on a `sqlite` database is used. This is recognizable by the single `.svn` folder in the top project folder, whereas the old (pre-1.7) file format uses one `.svn` folder per every local folder. A working copy based on the old format occupies about twice the space compared to a working copy based the new `sqlite` file format.