# Tortoise svn commit: "Delta source ended unexpectedly "

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, commit

I have a problem when I try to commit a certain file with Tortoise SVN (1.4.7). I have tried to svn delete and svn add the file. But with no luck - every time I try to commit a change in it, I get the error: "Delta source ended unexpectedly".

I have followed the advice in these 2 links:

[Tortoise SVN - Error:Delta Source Ended Unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137473/tortoise-svn-errordelta-source-ended-unexpectedly)
(top level delete of my local copy and recheck out)

and here:

http://blog.manontheground.net/traveller/2008/07/svndeltasourcee.html
(delete folder containing problematic file and do update)

with no luck.

I can commit changes in other files with no problem.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the advice offered by http://www.tomaz.me/2014/01/01/resolving-delta-source-ended-unexpectedly-svn-issue.html:

- delete the conflicting file from the repository
- commit the deletion
- add the file again
- commit the addition

This resolved the issue for me.

**EDIT**

As it turns out the fix above often helped to take care of the error for one commit only. Later on it reoccured. However, all affected files had spaces in their names. Renaming these files (e.g. eliminating the spaces) took care of the error more permanently.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to fix it by updating the repository from console. Not sure why update doesn't work with svn client in such cases.

You have to find the problem file and update it from the server copy.

**Step 1**. Use console command:

```
svn status
```

It will show with **!** sign problem files.

**Step 2**. Then run svn up commands for the directory the problem file is in.

```
svn up <directory> --set-depth=empty
svn up <directory> --set-depth=infinity
```